# Creating Movie Survey - PHP questions

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

Recently we had a project due that I did not do very well on. I know it wont help my current grade, but I think understanding the concepts will be extremely beneficial to me in the long run. The assignment was to create a movie survey.

**This is what I have so far for my formprocessor.php**

```
<body>
<H1><u>The Vermont Web Designers Movie Survey</u></h1>
<?php
//I want to hold the users information that they entered, so they know that this is their survey
$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
print "<p>$firstName $lastName's Movie Review - Spring 2018</p><hr>";

//I have values from 1 to 5 (ratings), I want to create a variable for each of them
$great = 0;
$good = 0;
$ok = 0;
$soso= 0;
$terrible = 0;

//I create an array to hold my selections. One for the movie ratings, another for the actor ratings.
$movieChoice = array($_POST['movie1'], $_POST['movie2'], $_POST['movie3']);
$actorChoice = array($_POST['actors1'], $_POST['actors2'], $_POST['actors3']);


//I use a loop to collect my movie choices.
for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){
    if($movieChoice[$i] == 1){
        //I increase the variable by 1 if it was selected.
        $great++;
    }
    else if($movieChoice[$i] == 2){
        $good++;
    } 
    else if($movieChoice[$i] == 3){
        $ok++;
    }
    else if($movieChoice[$i] == 4){
        $soso++;
    }
    else{
        $terrible++;
    }
}

//I use another loop to hold my actor selections.
for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){
    if($actorChoice[$i] == 1){
        $great++;
    }
    else if($actorChoice[$i] == 2){
        $good++;
    } 
    else if($actorChoice[$i] == 3){
        $ok++;
    }
    else if($actorChoice[$i] == 4){
        $soso++;
    }
    else{
        $terrible++;
    }
}

 print ('<table align= "center">
    <tr><th colspan= "3">Movie</th>
    <th>Question</th>
    <th>Great</th>
    <th>Good</th>
    <th>Ok</th>
    <th>So-So</th>
    <th>Terrible</th>
    </tr>

    <tr><td colspan= "3">1: The Godfather Part 1</td>
    <td>Quality of Movie</td>
    <td>'.$movieChoice[$great].'</td>
    <td>'.$movieChoice[$good].'</td>
    <td>'.$movieChoice[$ok].'&nbsp;</td>
    <td>'.$movieChoice[$soso].'</td>
    <td>'.$movieChoice[$terrible].'</td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td  colspan= "3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Quality of Actors</td>)
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td colspan= "3">2: Men of Honor</td>
    <td>Quality of Movie</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td  colspan= "3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Quality of Actors</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td colspan= "3">3: Three Days of the Condor</td>
    <td>Quality of Movie</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td  colspan= "3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Quality of Actors</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>');
```

?>

**This is my form**

```
<H1><u>The Vermont Web Designers Movie Survey</u></h1>
First Name: <input type= "text" size= "10" maxlength= "25" name= "firstName">
Last Name: <input type= "text" size= "10" maxlength= "25" name= "lastName"><br />
<hr>
<p>Please use a scale of 1 (first-rate; great; awesome) through 5 (really terrible) to answer each of these questions</p><br />
<hr>

<table align= "center"> 
    <tr><th colspan= "3">Movie </th>
    <th>Question</th>
    <th>Great</th>
    <th>Good</th>
    <th>Ok</th>
    <th>So-So</th>
    <th>Terrible</th>
    </tr>

    <tr><td colspan= "3">1: The Godfather Part 1</td>
    <td>Quality of Movie</td>
    <td><input type= "radio" name= "movie1" value="1">1</td>
    <td><input type= "radio" name= "movie1" value="2">2</td>
    <td><input type= "radio" name= "movie1" value="3">3</td>
    <td><input type= "radio" name= "movie1" value="4">4</td>
    <td><input type= "radio" name= "movie1" value="5">5</td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td  colspan= "3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Quality of Actors</td>
    <td><input type= "radio" name= "actors1" value="1">1</td>
    <td><input type= "radio" name= "actors1" value="2">2</td>
    <td><input type= "radio" name= "actors1" value="3">3</td>
    <td><input type= "radio" name= "actors1" value="4">4</td>
    <td><input type= "radio" name= "actors1" value="5">5</td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td colspan= "3">2: Men of Honor</td>
    <td>Quality of Movie</td>
    <td><input type= "radio" name= "movie2" value="1">1</td>
    <td><input type= "radio" name= "movie2" value="2">2</td>
    <td><input type= "radio" name= "movie2" value="3">3</td>
    <td><input type= "radio" name= "movie2" value="4">4</td>
    <td><input type= "radio" name= "movie2" value="5">5</td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td  colspan= "3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Quality of Actors</td>
    <td><input type= "radio" name= "actors2" value="1">1</td>
    <td><input type= "radio" name= "actors2" value="2">2</td>
    <td><input type= "radio" name= "actors2" value="3">3</td>
    <td><input type= "radio" name= "actors2" value="4">4</td>
    <td><input type= "radio" name= "actors2" value="5">5</td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td colspan= "3">3: Three Days of the Condor</td>
    <td>Quality of Movie</td>
    <td><input type= "radio" name= "movie3" value="1">1</td>
    <td><input type= "radio" name= "movie3" value="2">2</td>
    <td><input type= "radio" name= "movie3" value="3">3</td>
    <td><input type= "radio" name= "movie3" value="4">4</td>
    <td><input type= "radio" name= "movie3" value="5">5</td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td  colspan= "3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Quality of Actors</td>
    <td><input type= "radio" name= "actors3" value="1">1</td>
    <td><input type= "radio" name= "actors3" value="2">2</td>
    <td><input type= "radio" name= "actors3" value="3">3</td>
    <td><input type= "radio" name= "actors3" value="4">4</td>
    <td><input type= "radio" name= "actors3" value="5">5</td>
    </tr>
</table>

    <hr>
    <input type= "submit" value= "submit">
</form>
```

The real problem that I'm having trouble with is filling my array of movie choices, and actor choices, then printing that data for the user.

[**This is what I get when I run my code:**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIUUI.png)

[**This is what I should be getting**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxWug.png)

Comment: Your question is too broad. Start by narrow down the issues and take them one by one. If you can't figure one of them out, come back, remove all code that's not necessary to the issue at hand, show us the expected result and what result you're currently getting.

Comment: I tried to narrow down my code more to the exact issue. I added two images: one of what I am getting, the other what I should be getting.

Comment: It's hard to answer this @Melody.  Do you have more code that you can shorthand?  Do you have a database call that fetches results you've already received?

Comment: I hadn't set up a database for this project yet, just because I wanted to get the PHP down first. I will have to create a database, I was assuming to hold the choices for each users form. The teacher has been particularly bad at explaining this connection with php MySQL. I thought I could just make an array to hold the answers they gave, and then print them off. Then I would store the answers in my database.

Comment: Ok... Let me write something up for you real quick that will help you with that part of it.  Having a bit more data helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

DB Setup:

movies table
Fields: movie_id, movie_title

movie_ratings table
Fields: movie_ratings_id, movie_id, user_id, rating

actor_ratings table
Fields: actor_ratings_id, movie_id, user_id, rating

This way, you can store each individual rating individually, and do a COUNT and GROUP BY on your sql statement. That may get a little intense, since you're doing basic DB manipulation.  You could always do a SELECT *, and then increase your Movie Ratings based on something like below.

The scope of this is not within answering the question though, and if you'd like to message/chat me, I can help you out that way.

ORIGINAL ANSWER BELOW:

First get your results from the database

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ratings";
// fetch results
```

Now that you have the results, you can structure it properly
I would do something like this.  The reason I choose to do this is because then you have an associate array with named keys, and you'll be able to recall them later in a foreach loop or something similar.

```
$movieChoices = array(
    array('title'=>"The Godfather Part 1",
        'movieRatings' => array(
            "great" => 0,
            "good" => 0,
            "ok" => 0,
            "soso"=> 0,
            "terrible" => 0,
        ),
        'actorRatings' => array(
            "great" => 0,
            "good" => 0,
            "ok" => 0,
            "soso"=> 0,
            "terrible" => 0,
        )
    ),
    array('title'=> "Men Of Honor",
        'movieRatings' => array(
            "great" => 0,
            "good" => 0,
            "ok" => 0,
            "soso"=> 0,
            "terrible" => 0,
        ),
        'actorRatings' => array(
            "great" => 0,
            "good" => 0,
            "ok" => 0,
            "soso"=> 0,
            "terrible" => 0,
        )
    ),
    array('title'=>"Three Days of Condor",
        'movieRatings' => array(
            "great" => 0,
            "good" => 0,
            "ok" => 0,
            "soso"=> 0,
            "terrible" => 0,
        ),
        'actorRatings' => array(
            "great" => 0,
            "good" => 0,
            "ok" => 0,
            "soso"=> 0,
            "terrible" => 0,
        )
    )
);
```

Which will give you something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => The Godfather Part 1
            [movieRatings] => Array
                (
                    [great] => 0
                    [good] => 0
                    [ok] => 0
                    [soso] => 0
                    [terrible] => 0
                )

            [actorRatings] => Array
                (
                    [great] => 0
                    [good] => 0
                    [ok] => 0
                    [soso] => 0
                    [terrible] => 0
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Men Of Honor
            [movieRatings] => Array
                (
                    [great] => 0
                    [good] => 0
                    [ok] => 0
                    [soso] => 0
                    [terrible] => 0
                )

            [actorRatings] => Array
                (
                    [great] => 0
                    [good] => 0
                    [ok] => 0
                    [soso] => 0
                    [terrible] => 0
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => Three Days of Condor
            [movieRatings] => Array
                (
                    [great] => 0
                    [good] => 0
                    [ok] => 0
                    [soso] => 0
                    [terrible] => 0
                )

            [actorRatings] => Array
                (
                    [great] => 0
                    [good] => 0
                    [ok] => 0
                    [soso] => 0
                    [terrible] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

Store your post variables the same way for ease of code use.

```
$movieChoice = array($_POST['movie1'], $_POST['movie2'], $_POST['movie3']);
$actorChoice = array($_POST['actors1'], $_POST['actors2'], $_POST['actors3']);
```

Use a loop to store both items.
There's no sense in looping through the same thing twice.  Re use the code.
I use += 1, because it's more apparent what you're doing to the variable.
It's the same thing as ++, it's just my preference.

Also, while you're in here, you could write a SQL statement to update the row in the Database.

```
$sql = "UPDATE movie_ratings SET RATING = RATING + 1 WHERE movie_id = MOVIE_ID";
```

But, that's for later.  So go ahead and update your current values you already have.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    if ($movieChoice[$i] == 1) {
        //I increase the variable by 1 if it was selected.
        $movieChoices[$i]['movieRatings']["great"] += 1;
    } else if ($movieChoice[$i] == 2) {
        $movieChoices[$i]['movieRatings']['good'] += 1;
    } else if ($movieChoice[$i] == 3) {
        $movieChoices[$i]['movieRatings']['ok'] += 1;
    } else if ($movieChoice[$i] == 4) {
        $movieChoices[$i]['movieRatings']['soso'] += 1;
    } else {
        $movieChoices[$i]['movieRatings']['terrible'] += 1;
    }

    if ($actorChoice[$i] == 1) {
        //I increase the variable by 1 if it was selected.
        $movieChoices[$i]['actorRatings']["great"] += 1;
    } else if ($actorChoice[$i] == 2) {
        $movieChoices[$i]['actorRatings']['good'] += 1;
    } else if ($actorChoice[$i] == 3) {
        $movieChoices[$i]['actorRatings']['ok'] += 1;
    } else if ($actorChoice[$i] == 4) {
        $movieChoices[$i]['actorRatings']['soso'] += 1;
    } else {
        $movieChoices[$i]['actorRatings']['terrible'] += 1;
    }
}
```

Now when you want to print the results, it's even easier to do so.  You can use a `foreach()` loop to go through each movie result, and print their individual values out.  Much easier than what you were doing, less code.

```
print '
<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3">Movie</th>
        <th>Question</th>
        <th>Great</th>
        <th>Good</th>
        <th>Ok</th>
        <th>So-So</th>
        <th>Terrible</th>
    </tr>';

foreach($movieChoices as $choice) {
    print '
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">'.$choice['title'].'</td>
        <td>Quality of Movie</td>
        <td>'.$choice['movieRatings']['great'].'</td>
        <td>'.$choice['movieRatings']['good'].'</td>
        <td>'.$choice['movieRatings']['ok'].'&nbsp;</td>
        <td>'.$choice['movieRatings']['soso'].'</td>
        <td>'.$choice['movieRatings']['terrible'].'</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Quality of Actors</td>
        <td>'.$choice['actorRatings']['great'].'</td>
        <td>'.$choice['actorRatings']['good'].'</td>
        <td>'.$choice['actorRatings']['ok'].'&nbsp;</td>
        <td>'.$choice['actorRatings']['soso'].'</td>
        <td>'.$choice['actorRatings']['terrible'].'</td>
    </tr>
    ';
}
print '</table>';
```

In all honesty, this is a REALLY long result for this bit of code.  If I had more to work with, I could break it down to a lot simpler for you.  However, this will help with what you're trying to do.

Comment: The project is to to add in elementary database manipulation. 
He wants:

* The counts in the overall rating table increase when we sumbit the form for different people
*A movie rating table is produced (what I've mostly worked on)
*A clear button is added to the bottom of the report, that when clicked, clears the entire database.
* The clear button when clicked leards to a screen that asks you to either confirm that you wish to clear the entire database, or cancel your request.
*A table containing a list of users with their individual ratings is produced at the bottom (after the table)

Comment: Gotcha, well hopefully what I've set up will help you out.  Let me know if you need more help.  @Melody

Comment: Thanks I will. I added the form that I had taken out previously, and the top code where I put first and last name. How would you set up the database for this particular project? How many fields would that be? ID, Fname, Lname, movie 1, movie 2, movie 3?

Comment: @Melody - I'll update my answer with assistance in the DB

Comment: You have been so helpful! You mentioned that we could chat/message, and I would seriously appreciate it! ...I just don't know how to message on here, ahaha.

Comment: Yeah, you can get a hold of me via email cplsoup @ gmail

Answer (score 0):

I had some free time and decided to play around with your idea. You should be able to copy/paste this into a single file and it should work.

I don't intend my answer to be a final solution but I hope that it gives you some new ideas about to structure your program. Feel free to pick and choose what you will from it.

The main idea here is that it is storing the user's selections into the session so that we can increment it and display a running total in the last table. I tried to document the code as I went along but pls feel free to ask questions.

I've also tried to make it relatively dynamic so you can add movies, questions, choices and the form and form processor should handle it OK as long as you keep the data structures the same. The arrays that store the movies, choices, and questions also use associative keys (strings such as '1', '2' etc.) which slightly mimics what a relational DB would use. Add/remove elements to these arrays to see how the form changes.

Finally, there are some language constructs (??, square arrays []) which require PHP 7 to run. There are also some lines of code which are... ugly. I didn't try to find a nicer way to code them. 
Ex. `list($movieId, $questionId) = array_pad(explode('_', $key, 2), 2, null);`.

Let me know if you run into issues.

```
<?php
session_start();

// The following 3 arrays just store movie, choices, and questions
// which we will use in form processing and also to display the form to the user.
// Could come from DB, file, or hard-coded like this.
//
// Play around with these 3 arrays to see how the application changes.

// A list of movies.
$movies = [
    [
        'id' => '1',
        'title' => 'Taxi Driver',
        'director' => 'Mr. Scor-say-zee',
    ],
    [
        'id' => '2',
        'title' => 'The Mask',
        'director' => 'I do not know',
    ],
];

// A list of choices that a user can select.
$choices = [
    '1' => 'Terrible',
    '2' => 'So-So',
    '3' => 'OK',
    '4' => 'Good',
    '5' => 'Great',
];

// A list if rating categories.
$questions = [
    '1' => 'Quality of Movie',
    '2' => 'Quality of Actors',
    '3' => 'Quality of Producers',
];


// The reset button was clicked. Clear the session and redirect back to self.
if (isset($_POST['reset'])) {
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    die;
}

// The form was submitted. Store the user's selection in to the session.
// Storing it in the session for simplicity but could store it to a file or DB or some other persistent storage.
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    // Loop over the POST data and extract the question ID and movie ID for each submitted answer.
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

        // The incoming POST data looks like: 1_1, 2_1, 2_2 etc.
        // Split the string on the underscore which will give us the movie ID and question ID respectively.
        // Once we know which movie and question is submitted store them, along with the actual rating, in the session.
        // If it doesn't exist in the session, set it to 1.
        // If it does exist in the session, just increment the value.
        list($movieId, $questionId) = array_pad(explode('_', $key, 2), 2, null);

        if (is_numeric($questionId) && is_numeric($movieId)) {

            // Check if it is in the session already.
            if (!isset($_SESSION['ratings'][$movieId][$questionId][$value])) {
                $_SESSION['ratings'][$movieId][$questionId][$value] = 1;
            } else {
                $_SESSION['ratings'][$movieId][$questionId][$value] = $_SESSION['ratings'][$movieId][$questionId][$value] + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

?>

<!-- Display the form -->
<form method="post">
    <?php
    foreach ($movies as $movie) {

        echo '<h2>' . $movie['title'] . '</h2>';

        foreach ($questions as $questionId => $questionDescription) {
            echo '<h3>' . $questionDescription . '</h3>';
            foreach ($choices as $choiceValue => $choiceDescription) {
                // Each row will have a name like: 1_1, 1_2, 2_1 etc.
                // These represent the movie ID and question ID respectively.
                // During form processing (above) we split the name on the underscore which give use the movie ID and question ID that the user submitted.
                // There is a probably a better way to do this.
                echo '<label>';
                echo '<input type= "radio" name= "' . $movie['id'] . '_' . $questionId . '" value="' . $choiceValue . '">';
                echo $choiceDescription;
                echo '</label>';
            }
        }

        echo '<hr />';
    }
    ?>

    <br>
    <br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    <input type="submit" name="reset" value="Reset">

</form>

<!-- Display the results from the session -->
<table border="1">
    <caption>Favorite and Least Favorite Things</caption>
    <tr>
        <th>Movie</th>
        <th>Question</th>
        <?php
        echo "<th>" . implode('</th> <th>', $choices) . "</th>";
        ?>
    </tr>

    <?php
    foreach ($movies as $movie) {
        echo '<tr>';

        // Notice the rowspan grows with each question added.
        echo '<th rowspan="' . count($questions) . '">' . $movie['title'] . '</th>';

        foreach ($questions as $questionId => $questionDescription) {

            // Open a new row on the 2nd and subsequent iterations.
            if ((int)$questionId > 1) {
                echo '<tr>';
            }

            echo '<th>' . $questionDescription . '</th>';

            // Output the actual ratings from the session.
            foreach ($choices as $choiceId => $choiceDescription) {
                echo '<th>';
                echo $_SESSION['ratings'][$movie['id']][$questionId][$choiceId] ?? 0;
                echo '</th>';
            }
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    ?>
</table>
```